# How to create bubble notifications on Android?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, notifications, capacitor

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpDKwjpZV9Q) @ 0:17 shows a bubble-style push notification on Android. Messaging apps like WhatsApp often use these.

I'm building an app with Capacitor 3 but can't find how to send these kinds of push notifications. Is there a plugin I could use, or some way of configuring just a normal push notification to display like this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is the default style when the 'brief' notification style is selected in the notifications setting on the phone. It isn't set programmatically as some kind of notification config.

Mine wasn't showing because the 'Show as popup' option was disabled for the notification channel I was testing. When I created a new channel, it was set to show notifications as popups, and then they started showing like in the video.